# Cherry picking a range of commits in Git

Tags: git, merge, git-cherry-pick

I was hoping to get some ideas. I have three branches:

- master
- specific
- feature-branch

`master` contains the generic code base so that if I want to branch out later to create a new type of implementation, I can easily do so. But for now `specific` is my main development branch.

So I branched `specific` off into `feature-branch` to test a new feature, once I was satisfied I merged `feature-branch` back into `specific`.

But there are some commits which are implementation specific in `specific` which I don't want to merge back into master. Most of the code is generic changes, which I do want to merge back.

I merged about 30 changes from `feature-branch` into `specific`. Of those 30, probably about 20 I want to merge from `specific` into `master`.

What is the best way for me to do this?

Should I just cherry pick each of the commits I want to merge into `master`? If so, should I just go in reverse chronological order (ie. get the oldest commit I want to merge in, then the second oldest, and so on - cherry picking them all back into `master`).

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is best (if you haven't pushed `specific` to any remote repo yet) to:

- reorder your commits in the `specific` branch (the one for `master`, then the implementation-specific one), with an [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/).
- merge only the 20 first commits to `master` (that will be a fast-forward merge)
  You can create a temporary branch on the most recent of those 20 commits (`git branch tmp SHA1`), and merge that branch (`git checkout master ; git merge tmp`)

That way, no [cherry-picking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309), meaning no duplication of commits.

---

If specific has been pushed, then cherry-picking can work, starting from the older to the newest commit.

> In the "`cherry-pick A..B`" form, `A` should be older than `B`.
>   If they're the wrong order the command will silently fail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. `specific` has already been pushed remotely unfortunately...

Comment: @b85411 ok, I have edited the answer to cover both scenarios.